# Is there a way to make a non-redirecting search engine?

Tags: html, search-engine

I'm trying to make a search engine, that will display every website content inside of the website, meaning that the computer won't detect that you even went on the website.

**what I have tried:**

I have tried to use the `fetch` function, and it did work, but there were 2 problems:

1. Only the html code displayed, so there was no css, or is, unless it was in the  or  tag.
2. 90% of fetched websites returned an error, stating that I needed to enable something in my fetch command, but when I did, no html content popped up.

I've also tried using an api that somebody made, and it did work well, but upon clicking an  tag, it redirected you to the actual site

I'm trying to achieve what [this website](https://mathpath.xyz) has done, so I can get past website blocking.

Comment: It sounds like you want a private proxy server or VPN.

Comment: Not really, what I'm looking for is a website that acts like a vpn (kinda), and the machine I'm going to run the website on can't use vpns

Comment: So a CGI proxy.